# $\int_{\partial \Omega}\frac{\partial u}{\partial N}d\sigma $ if $\Delta u = 0$ in $\Omega$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Can you help me please with this problem?

1. What do you know about $\int_{\partial \Omega}\frac{\partial u}{\partial N}d\sigma $ if $\Delta u  = 0$ in $\Omega$?
2. Is it always possible to solve an equation $u''=0$ in $[0,1]$ if $u'(0)$ and  $u'(1)$ are given?(What is connection to first question?) Is the solution - unique?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: $\Delta u = \mbox{div} \nabla u$. Do you know the divergence theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one

From the divergence theorem for the vector field $ \text{grad} u$ we get that:

$\displaystyle{ \int_{\Omega} \text{div(grad u}) \nu = \int_{\partial \Omega} < \text{grad}u ,N> \sigma} \quad (\bigstar)$

where $\nu$ is the volume element.

Using now the ypothesis that $ 0=\Delta u := \text{div(grad u)}$ and that $\displaystyle{\frac{\partial u}{\partial N} := <\text{grad g ,N}>}$

The conclusion now follows from $(\bigstar)$.

Comment: Uhmm -- which conclusion?

Comment: @passenger Thanks! Can you please explain it in more detailed way?

Comment: Since $\Delta u =0$ the left hand side of $(\star)$ is $0$ and so does the right hand side which is exactly what you want.